# Android Studio: Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

Tags: android-studio-3.0, build-error

Installed latest version of the Android Studio.

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 13
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.7762732, built on September 24, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.5.31-release-551-AS7442.40)
```

Unable to build the project: Build is failing everytime. Below is the error log:
Checked the proxy setting, seems not needed because SDK updates & Gradle sync are happening without any issues.
Please advice if I'm missing anything.

> ```
> > Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\MyOrganizer
> > 
> > IOException:
> > https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-5.xml
> > java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect IOException:
> > https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-4.xml
> > java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect IOException:
> > https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
> > java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect IOException:
> > https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
> > java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect IOException:
> > https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
> > java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect Failed to
> > download any source lists! IO exception while downloading manifest:
> > java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect  at
> > java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)  at
> > java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
> >     at
> > java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
> >     at
> > java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
> >     at
> > java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
> >     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)   at
> > java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)  at
> > java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)   at
> > java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
> >     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:526)
> >     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:524)
> >     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
> > Method)     at
> > java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:523)
> >     at
> > java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:564)
> >     at
> > java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)
> >     at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:203)
> >     at
> > java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1232)
> >     at
> > java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
> >     at
> > java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)
> >     at
> > java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
> >     at
> > com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:245)
> >     at
> > com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:622)
> >     at
> > com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:545)
> >     at
> > com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyDownloader.downloadAndStream(LegacyDownloader.java:65)
> >     at
> > com.android.repository.impl.downloader.LocalFileAwareDownloader.downloadAndStream(LocalFileAwareDownloader.java:51)
> >     at
> > 
> > 
> > * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> > 
> > BUILD FAILED in 14s
> ```

Please advice a fix. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever fine a solution for this?

Comment: What happens when you try to access `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-4.xml` in a browser?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should go to SDK Manager and install the new Platform-tools

   [image]
2. Go to File -> Project Structure -> Modules and select the Properties Tab from the top of the right column
3. Choose your Build Tools Version and click on ok.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Install build platform tool 30.0.3 from sdk manager using android studio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).